# Spacing in Paragraph

Tags: html

can anyone ask me how I am able to get the spacing shown in my example? I tried multiple methods like but it has the extra white space that I do not want.

Example.

```
My interest
     Hi I am Bob. I work somewhere here, I do things I like, I love pet, I like cat
     and I love sports
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post what you have done so far. If you need help please use the following guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are two main spacing methods in css, `padding` and `margin`.

`padding` adds space **inside** an element you apply this property. Let's say you have an element `<span>` with `padding-left: 12px;`, so the content of this element will have a gap of 12px to the left. Sometimes you have to be careful when using `padding` in combination with explict `width`. For instance, if an element's width is 200px and you add `padding: 20px;` (so 20px on the top, right, bottom and left) the new width of the element will be 240px instead of 200px. To prevent this *"growing"* you can add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your element.

`margin` adds a space **between** to elements. So let's say there are to `<span>` elements with `display: block` (so they are displayed below each other). They have also the property `margin-top: 20px;`, so they will have a margin on the top to their neighbour elements of 20px.

Here is a code example with some spacing methods. Notice the difference of the elements `<span class="description">`. As I said with `padding` is the gap inside the box, with `margin` outside.

```css
.example-1{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #dedede;
    width: 300px;
    /* Add some padding to the container */
    padding: 4px 12px; /* top-bottom and right-left padding */
    box-sizing: border-box; /*Div should stay in 300px width */
    /* Margin to the next example */
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.example-1 > .title{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}

.example-1 > .description{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
    text-align: justify;
}

.example-2{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #dedede;
    width: 300px;
    /* Add some padding to the container */
    padding: 4px 12px; /* top-bottom and right-left padding */
    box-sizing: border-box; /*Div should stay in 300px width */
}

.example-2 > .title{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}

.example-2 > .description{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-1">
    <span class="title">Example with padding</span>
    <span class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
    accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
</div>

<div class="example-2">
    <span class="title">Example with margin</span>
    <span class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
    accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @michaeIT is there a way to extend the block? it seems to squeeze all the text inside the block

Comment: Which block? The grey one? You can simply change the `width: 300px;` line to another size. E.g. `100%` to fit the element into the parent.

Comment: I figured it out thanks man! Do you know how to remove white spaces above a text?